# Webpack - CSS Minification and Bundle

Tags: webpack, bundle, minify, webpack-4, webpack-cli

Almost three hours of research and here I am asking for community help.

I have an project with the following CSSs:

- **The ones being used by every page** (generics): `buttons.css`, `tables.css`, `forms.css` and`lists.css`
- **The one being used only by a specific HTML page**: `page-custom-buttons.css`.

**For the ones being used by every page** I want to bundle them and minify into a single file.
The one being used only by a specific page I just want to minify them.

From the many guides, questions and documentation I have walk though I found the following things:

- The `extract-text-webpack-plugin` is now deprecated and `mini-css-extract-plugin`instead.
- We can use `mini-css-extract-plugin` to bundle the CSSs.
- We can use `optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin` to optimize it but it will require the installation of another package for dealing with js minifier (more about [here](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/#minimizing-for-production))

The `MiniCssExtractPlugin` description says

> This plugin extracts CSS into separate files. It creates a CSS file per JS file which contains CSS. It supports On-Demand-Loading of CSS and SourceMaps.

From the little I understand from the definition and the examples this shouldn't be used as a bundler but instead for giving the funcionallity of importing CSS from JS code like we do in react (`import './styles.css'`).

**The real questions are**, don't webpack fit in this type of problems? Should I use other software? What does MiniCssExtractPlugin really do and what's the different between the `css-loader`. How can I do bundle myfiles and minifying them correctly?

I found a similiar unanswsered question: https://dev.to/shaijut/how-to-bundle-mutiple-js-and-css-files-into-single-bundle-2a70

Thank you for someone who might reply to this answer. Anyhing you know helpful!

Comment: No one will tell you how to do it, you build the project and you should know what will be more useful. If you don't use webpack for js bundles but only for scss then you don't need webpack. All you have to do is use node-sass from the command line and postcss to compile scss -> css is enough. If you want to build js + scss then webpack is a good solution. I use mini-css-extract-plugin + splitChunks in my projects I divide everything into individual chunks, e.g. styles with pages and one common style. The same applies to js. Here you have an example [blog](https://github.com/tomik23/photoBlog)

Comment: I'm using webpack for bundle JS, and now I just wanted to bundle and minify my css files...